# Pressing Enter is not the same as clicking the Windows Form's AcceptButton

Tags: vb.net, validation

I have a simple VB.Net Windows Forms application with two TextBoxes and a Button which is the form's AcceptButton. The only code is on the ButtonClick, and validation for each TextBox using the Leave event. (I tried the LostFocus event also, and it seems to work the same). My problem is that if I click the Button with the mouse, then the proper Leave (or LostFocus) event happens for the TextBox that the user was in, but If I press Enter, focus is not lost and so the code for that TextBox does not run.

How can I make the Enter Key behave the same way as clicking the form's AcceptButton?

Comment: Why not put the validation code in the click event?  Whatever they type is all tentative until they press Enter/Submit/Ok/Done anyway.

Comment: Can't each form field do its own validation as I go through the form? I am told that immediate validation is best, and waiting until the Submit is poor UX. Also, less Object Oriented. I could have done just as well with Petzold's book in 1992 and C.

Comment: Field by field validation, by definition, means you will be popping up MsgBoxs or whatever as they navigate the form, which everyone finds intrusive.  FxF also only works with simple apps - in other cases, the validation for B depends on A, which means you can have a deadlock if they change A after you validate B.  As for OO, if the contents of the form represent something like a `Customer` or `Widget`, validating the inputs as a whole is completely OO.

Comment: Also, Rule #1 of the old WDIG was *The User is in charge* which means they can enter the data in any order they like, tabbing/skipping over fields to get to something else.  An example would be a CSR on the phone - if the customer doesnt have the data in the order your form expects, things ought not come to a screeching halt.  Or they can type "I Like Pie" for an age, they cannot however submit it.

Comment: @Plutonix: I have both validation for each field, and a Click validation that makes sure that the two entries are compatible with each other... It is a teaching example, and a pretty good one I think. Empty field - OK until Submit. Invalid data - not OK to leave the field. My approach delegates levels of responsibility for different things to different methods, and I was doing it a long time before Windows, OO and frameworks. (I just had a hiatus to do something else for a while.) I wish I could post the finished app somewhere...

Comment: Also, my field validation uses Error Provider, which I am told is the preferred way to give feedback - of course far better than message boxes. I am trying to follow the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click directly on the button there is a chain of events including `TextBox.LostFocus`, `TextBox.Leave`, `Button.MouseEnter`, `Button.Click`

But when you press Enter it's the Form which intercept the keypress and if it's Enter and there is an AcceptButton then launch it's `PerformClick` method without raising most of those events.

*You could easily verify that ; set your Button's DialogResult on one value via designer and handle your Button's GotFocus event when you change that DialogResult for another value.
Then test your code (store the result of `Form.ShowDialog`) ; with direct click you'll get the value set on GotFocus because it's during the Click the form set it's DialogResult on the button's DialogResult value ; with a press to Enter you'll get the initial Dialogresult (the designer one) effectively proving that GotFocus wasn't entered.*

Back to the current problem ; to solve it you need to handle your validation in `Validating` (or `Validated`) event ; be sure that your Textbox `CauseValidation` is set to true [the default value] otherwise those event aren't raised. You could inside them set `e.Cancel` (with e the CancelEventArgs argument) to true to stop validation (and the chain of events) effectively sticking focus inside the "invalidated" control (and which also prevents the button's click whatever way was used to reach it)

one example : this form has two Textboxes and one Button as the Form's AcceptButton and "validate" it's input so that no empty TextBox.Text are allowed

```
Public Class NonEmptyTextBoxesForm
    Private Sub TextBoxes_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating, TextBox2.Validating
        Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
        e.Cancel = tb.Text = "" ' e.Cancel = (tb.Text = "") ' if that's make this clearer
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Wow. Mouse and Keyboard do not work the same. What a mess! OK, I will change the name of my functions from Leave to Validating and catch that event instead. I hope that Validating happens if I press Enter, or there will be a small problem.

Comment: It's not really that mouse and keyboard don't work the same (if you change focused control with textbox (with tab for example) the chain of events is the same as with mouse. In your precise case it's the Form the "responsible" which intercept the keypress and supercedes the chain of events.

Comment: Ding Ding Ding! I changed the word "Leave" to "Validating" in 4 places and now it works the way I expect. They need a bit more documentation on that. I am trying to find a flowchart showing the events triggered in various scenarios, but I haven't seen one yet.

Comment: see the _Notes_ part in [Validating documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example ;)

Comment: Hmm, the word "notes" does not appear anywhere on that web page? I saw the Caution not to use Focus(). I would instead have to use e.Cancel to prevent leaving the field, as you say.

Comment: sorry in the _Remarks_ section ; was seeing the page in my native language

Answer (score 0):

So you are losing focus from textbox to the button when you click Enter Key?!
If this is that, you can try out this:

```
   Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef sMessage As Message, ByVal oKeyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If oKeyData = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.Textbox1.Focus()
        AcceptButton.PerformClick()
        Return True
    ElseIf oKeyData = Keys.Escape Then
        Application.Exit()
        Return True
    Else
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(sMessage, oKeyData)
    End If
   End Function
```

> I hope this helped you ;)

Comment: No, I am NOT getting the LostFocus (or Leave) event when I press the Enter key, but it DOES happen with the mouse click. So, all these years of having Windows and frameworks and I still have to intercept keyboard events to run a simple form? Fail.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Plutonix - why not just put the validation for both text boxes in the click event?  (unless this is for education purposes?)

If you really want to validate on the text boxes' leave events, and you need the validation on the current text box to run before whatever the button does when you hit enter, then you need a key press event to handle key press for both text boxes.  In that, check if the key pressed was enter, and if so then you could just get the text box that has focus...call it's leave event, and then call the button's click event.

Does that make sense?

Comment: So, Windows was not designed so that pressing Enter with AcceptButton set is equivalent to clicking said button? And I have to work around a design flaw in Windows? I thought that keyboard navigation and mouse navigation was supposed to be equivalent. You asked why I want each TextBox to have a function to validate itself instead of one big validation function: because it is more Object Oriented?

Answer (score 0):

How can I make the Enter Key behave the same way as clicking the form's AcceptButton?

To make the ENTER key behave the same as clicking the ACCEPT button you can use the ACCEPTBUTTON property of the form and assign the button you wish to be clicked when the ENTER key is pressed.

Although this will cause the code in the button's click event to execute,
I do not know if the code in the TEXTBOX-LOSTFOCUS event will execute or not!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  '
  ' Assign default button for ENTER key (Okay Button)
  Me.AcceptButton = Me.MyOkayButton
  '
  ' Assign default button for ESCAPE key (Cancel Button)
  Me.CancelButton = Me.MyCancelButton
  '
End Sub
```

Comment: I have set the AcceptButton property in the form itself, not the code. Is there a vital difference? Pressing Enter does DO what the Click event says, it just DOES NOT do the LostFocus / Leave stuff... Yet clicking with the mouse does. Why would I want Enter to trigger different events than Clicking?

Comment: By setting the ACCEPTBUTTON or CANCELBUTTON it simply picks up the enter/escape key when pressed and executes the nominated button event. The BEST place to place your validation code would be in the VALIDATING and VALIDATED events as Sehnsucht wrote above. A lot of designers like to validate all the data at once when the form is submitted in the button click event, at times like that you would use the ACCEPTBUTTON to run THAT button event. If you want each textbox to validate its own data then you should follow Sehnsucht's model. That is the reason those events exist.

Comment: Yes, I changed the event to Validating and it mostly works the way I was expecting. It seems odd to me that clicking with the mouse includes the action of first leaving the current field, yet pressing Enter - which is supposed to do exactly the same thing in terms of navigation - does NOT leave the current field. How can this difference in behavior be explained? Is there a scenario where I would want them to do different things? I can't imagine one. I see this as a design flaw in Windows.